# Spring Boot 2+ Thymeleaf 3.0.10 Exception handling- Not able to return error.html

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using SpringBoot2 and Thymeleaf 3.0.10 version, i want to handle the thymeleaf exceptions by using ErrorController using /error path. And I'm succeeded to get the  error into controller. But it is not returning my custom error view page(/error). It returning the page which I have error(/errorPageUrl).

My Controller class is

```
@Controller 
public class AppErrorController extends AbstractControllerImpl implements ErrorController {

private static final String PATH = "/error";

@Autowired
private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

@RequestMapping(value = PATH)
public ModelAndView error(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    ServletWebRequest webRequest = new ServletWebRequest(request);
    PageError pageError = new PageError(response.getStatus(), getErrorAttributes(webRequest, true), false);
    mav.addObject("pageError", pageError);
    mav.setViewName("common/error");
    log.error("Page Error: " + pageError.error + "\n" + pageError.trace);
    return mav;
}

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return PATH;
}

private Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(ServletWebRequest request, boolean includeStackTrace) {
    return errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(request, includeStackTrace);
}
}
```

Here I'm getting error path and then I'm redirecting to "common/error" page. But it is redirecting to another page which i have error fragment "testing/testEntries".

Stacktrace is

```
00:43:07,689 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-21) UT005023: Exception handling request to /XXXX/error: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/common/error.html]")
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:274)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:209)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:221)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:147)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:180)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:145)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/common/error.html]")
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
... 67 more Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "testing/testEntries" - line 24, col 32)
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
... 78 more
```

I looked into error.html. it is fine, i'm not using anything here. I'm just showing PageError class attributes.

This error controller is working fine with SpringBoot 1.5.7 and Thymeleaf 2.x.
Is there anything i missed here?

**Update** error.html

```
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="~{common/layout}">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/common/error.css}" />
</head> 
<body>
    <!--/* This error page is shown if any exception occurs during the Thymeleaf processing of the page/view. Typically caused by a thymeleaf syntax error or null view objects */-->
    <th:block layout:fragment="topBar"></th:block>
    <th:block layout:fragment="sideBar"></th:block>

    <!--/* Error Page Content */--> 
    <th:block layout:fragment="content">
        <div id="errorInfo" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="header">
                <span class="prefix">Error </span>
                <span class="cls" th:text="${pageError?.status}"></span>: &nbsp;<span class="cls" th:text="${pageError?.error}"></span>
            </div>          
            <div class="header">
                <span class="msg" th:text="${pageError?.message}"></span>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnDetail">Show Detail</button>
            <pre class="detail display-none" id="detailContent" th:text="${pageError?.trace}"></pre>
        </div>      
    </th:block> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Update 2**
Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.fami.app</groupId>
<artifactId>app-builder</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>app-builder</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <poi.version>3.13</poi.version>
    <app.version>1.0.0</app.version>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>web</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- This files should not exist. Will force it to not run tests -->
            <jUnitInclude>**/SkipTests.java</jUnitInclude>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <!-- Profile to enable specific jUnits Test to be ran, This will be executed on certain regions in harvest to validate code. -->
        <id>smokeTest</id>
        <properties>
            <!-- This is the jUnit Test case to add your jUnit tests to. Please read the java doc on the file for more information -->
            <jUnitInclude>**/SkipTests.java</jUnitInclude>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Plugin to specify jUnit Tests-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <!-- Parameter should be initialized in the profile section -->
                    <include>${jUnitInclude}</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- saxon - XSLT and XQuery Processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- saxon-dom - added this dependency for the print batch xml conversion -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.8</version>
        <classifier>dom</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Oracle Wallet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>oraclepki</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>osdt_cert</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>osdt_core</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Oracle Wallet -->
    <!-- apache common libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HTTPClient - web client API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jDom for XML processing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cobertura-plugin</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-findbugs-plugin</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**Update 3**

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {
@Bean
    public CustomThymeleafDialect myDialect() {
        return new CustomThymeleafDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setProducePartialOutputWhileProcessing(false);
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(getTemplateEngine());
        resolver.setCache(false);
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LayoutDialect layoutDialect() {
        return new LayoutDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect securityDialect() {
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver getResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setOrder(2);
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine getTemplateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.addDialect(layoutDialect());
        engine.addDialect(securityDialect());
        engine.addDialect(myDialect());
        engine.setTemplateResolver(getResolver());
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return engine;
    }
    }
```

**Update 5**
This Configurations working for syntax errors like (missing closing tag of anchor like that..), when it comes to binding results like th:field="*{test.testingString}" it is not working.. am i missing something to configure for this?

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml ?

Comment: Just replace the error.html with a simple `<h1>hi</h1>` message and see if that works? You would know what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @Karthik R i already tried that.. but no luck for me. Same error there. I will update my question with pom.xml

Comment: @Avijit Barua i just updated the question with my pom.xml

Comment: please post AbstractControllerImpl

Comment: Hi @Nitheesh Chandran.. AbstractControlImpl is the class for getting Log object nothing more than that. I removed that and tried. But no use.. Anyway i will update the question with Configuration class.

Comment: @Confuser Your AppErrorController  Works fines for me

Comment: @NitheeshChandran it has only problem with Thymeleaf 1.3.10 version. are you using same version of Thymeleaf?

Comment: @Confuser Sorry No

Answer (score 0):

```
nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/common/error.html]
```

By the above exception looks like you are missing a closing tag somewhere.Please check your html page whether all the tags are closed properly.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Alien. I checked the entire error.html page. looks fine. it is the error in "testing/testEntries" page. I handle this error in ErrorController and return "common/error". But still i got  "testing/testEntries" this exception when returning to error page as a NestedException. I don't understand this behaviour with thymeleaf 3.0.10 and Spring Boot2.